# How to make part of emacs configuration buffer or mode local with Emacs server enabled?

Tags: emacs, server, client

I heard that many people use Emacs client to boost up the speed, but when I try it I met some problems.

Here is an example to help explaining.
I have semantic mode hooked to C++ mode, which means if I open a C++ file then semantic mode will be fired up. But since the semantic mode is opened in the server, it won't disappear with the client. Then if I open a python script the semantic mode will also be there which is not wanted.

More generally, most of the evaluated lisp functions in one buffer will have an effect on other buffers and in most of the time these effect are not welcomed.

I got wondering is there any method that I can restrain part of configuration to buffer local? So that I can have part of configurations for all the buffers while some others only live within a specific buffer or with a specific mode? In another word, I want to make the effect of some evaluated functions disappear or got restored when I leave that buffer. Searching Google didn't get any related answer.

Answer (score 0):

The clients are simply an *interface* for accessing your Emacs instance. A window into the server, if you like.  They do not have their own elisp environment; if you need that, you need to run multiple instances of Emacs.

Comment: It's it possible to limit the effect in a specific buffer like limiting the variable as buffer-local?

Comment: Any variable can have a buffer-local value, but you cannot make *arbitrary* changes to the elisp environment which are effective in only one buffer (or frame/terminal/client), so you need to ask *specific* questions. I recommend posting a new question(s) explaining the *exact* things you are having trouble with, and people can then help with individual issues.

Answer (score 0):

From the emacs perspective, there is no difference between doing something via emacsclient and doing it in just normal emacs. So, the problem you are seeing must also be a problem when just running normal emacs.

We need more information to understand what precisely is your concern. What is the issue with semantic mode running - is it causing problems with python coding?

Not that you can turn of semantic mode with M-x sematnic-mode.

the problem cold be how you are starting semantic mode. For example, it is common to ut it in a hood, but if you have used something like prog-mode-hook rather than c++-mode-hook, then it will be started whenever you run a programming mode (or a mode that is derived from prog-mode).

If you provide more details on how you are starting semantic-mode and what the actual problem is your seeing when you try to switch to programming python, we may be able to provide more specific assistance.

Comment: The semantic mode is just as an example here. I have some specific configuration functions for different major modes, semantic is part of the c++ mode configuration. Some of these configurations will last even if I change to a different major mode while some others will disappear. So what I want is to make all those configurations act like a local variable, when I enter a specific major mode or buffer, they got evaluated, after I leave that major mode or buffer it will restore to the state before the configuration functions evaluated. Or just make two buffers acts like two different processes.

Comment: You need to provide specific examples. In particular, show how a configuration in one mode is affecting another mode - for example, you have a key binding in C++, mode, but don't want that key binding in python mode. Generally, if you have some configuraiton for a mode which is affecting an unrelated mode, the configuration is defined/loaded at the wrong level i.e. wrong hook, wrong keymap etc. Sometimes you just need to put a turn on/turn off in an appropriate hook, but without specific examples, I cannot provide more

Comment: So I have elpy configured for python mode, if semantic mode is activated in python mode it will tell me the import modules not found. But actually I don't need semantic mode when coding python since I have elpy already. Also, if I open a c file after opening python file, the virtual env is there which is not needed when coding in c. I want them isolated.

Comment: You pick tough examples! Elpy is a little unusual as it isn't so much a mode as some code which glues a number of different modes together which are useful with doing python code in emacs. This can make itt a bit tricky to find exactly the bit you need to configure. However, I suspect the sematnic-inhibit-functions approach mentioned in other comments is your best bet for turning off semantic support when in python mode.

Answer (score 0):

`semantic-mode` is a global minor mode, which means you can't disable it for individual buffers or major modes.  However, there's a hook `semantic-inhibit-functions` that you can use.

```
(defun jpk/semantic-inhibit-function ()
  (eq major-mode 'python-mode))
(add-hook 'semantic-inhibit-functions #'jpk/semantic-inhibit-function)
```

This is basically the opposite of this answer: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/15143/651.

---

General answer, which doesn't really apply to this question:

The normal way to do per-major-mode things is with hooks.  Every major mode has a hook, usually called `foo-mode-hook` for e.g. `foo-mode`.  It's a list of functions that get called when the major mode is activated.  There are other hooks like `prog-mode-hook`, which gets called for pretty much every programming major mode; C-like languages also have `c-common-mode-hook`.

```
(defun jpk/python-mode-hook ()
  (semantic-mode -1))
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook #'jpk/python-mode-hook)
```

I recommend using `defun`s for hooks instead of `lambda`s, because then it's easy to use `remove-hook`.

If you want to do per-buffer things, use file local variables, or look at the `(buffer-name)` in your major mode hook.

Comment: I understand the hooks. In the question I said semantic is hooked to c++ mode. But after leaving c++ mode, the semantic mode is still activated.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't familiar with `semantic-mode`.  It's a global minor mode, so you can't turn it off for single buffers.  But there is a hook called `semantic-inhibit-functions` that should do what you want.